# How to group by multiple column and select top 1 value using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following code with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- structure(list(barcodes = c("scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", "scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", 
"scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", "scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", "scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", 
"scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", "scA22_CAACAGCAACAG", "scA22_TTTTTTTTTTTT"
), gene_name = c("A930037H05Rik", "A930037H05Rik", "A930037H05Rik", 
"A930037H05Rik", "Lgals8", "Lgals8", "Lgals8", "Lgals8"), tsse = c(0.152777777777778, 
0.152777777777778, 0.152777777777778, 0.00192307692307692, 0.055, 
0.0485294117647059, 0.033, 0.0294642857142857)), na.action = structure(integer(0), .Names = character(0)), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(dat)

dat
```

It produces this:

```
             barcodes     gene_name        tsse
1: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.152777778
2: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.152777778
3: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.152777778
4: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.001923077
5: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG        Lgals8 0.055000000
6: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG        Lgals8 0.048529412
7: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG        Lgals8 0.033000000
8: scA22_TTTTTTTTTTTT        Lgals8 0.029464286
```

What I want to do is to group by `c("barcodes", "gene_name")`
and then select based on `tsse`.

Resulting in:

```
             barcodes     gene_name        tsse
1: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.152777778
2: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG        Lgals8 0.055000000
3: scA22_TTTTTTTTTTTT        Lgals8 0.029464286
```

How can I achieved that with data.table. In reality, I have around 300million lines
to produce. So I need speed with data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which.max` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .SD[which.max(tsse)], .(barcodes, gene_name)]

#             barcodes     gene_name   tsse
#1: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.1528
#2: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG        Lgals8 0.0550
#3: scA22_TTTTTTTTTTTT        Lgals8 0.0295
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you could set keys and pick the last of each group:

```r
setkey(dat, barcodes, gene_name, tsse)
dat[, tail(.SD, 1), .(barcodes, gene_name)]
#>              barcodes     gene_name       tsse
#> 1: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG A930037H05Rik 0.15277778
#> 2: scA22_CAACAGCAACAG        Lgals8 0.05500000
#> 3: scA22_TTTTTTTTTTTT        Lgals8 0.02946429
```

Comment: I suspect of the three approaches suggested, yours will be fastest. But it's hard to simulate a good ssRNA seq dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
setorder(dat, barcodes, gene_name, -tsse)
dat[c(TRUE, diff(rleid(barcodes, gene_name))>0L)]
```

Will be interested to know the timing on the  actual dataset